# How do I create an Amazon version of my android app?

Tags: android, google-play, amazon-appstore

I already have an app in the Google Play Store, and want to put it in Amazon's App Marketplace.

The only thing that is different is that the app includes a screen which goes to the Google Play listing for rating purposes.

What's the simplest way to create a different APK for Amazon?

Thanks!

EDIT:

Is there a way to do this through something like compiler options? I'm thinking back to when I used Delphi, and you could create a separate project that used the same source, but had custom compiler options that you could then use to conditionally include or exclude parts of the code. The result was that you could have a single set of code that produced different executables depending on which project you compiled.

So I'm wondering if there is something similar in Eclipse.

Comment: You don't need to create a different apk. You just need to change that one thing in the app to point to amazon and create a new release build for their store...

Comment: You can consider using `gradle`. `Gradle` supports `productFlavors`, you can essentially use a combination of different/same source/resources to build your apk. Have a look at this - https://github.com/varunkochar/Trying-Android-Gradle/tree/master/ProductFlavorsAndBuildTypes/ProductFlavorsAndBuildTypes . Look at the `build.gradle` and how the project is setup.

Comment: @Neil was right for what I needed to do. In the end it was just a single line in the strings.xml file, so I just included both lines, and comment out the one that is not needed for the particular build.

That's fine for a simple change, but in the long run I'd like a more controlled way of doing it for more complex differences.  When it comes to that I'll have a look at what I can do with Gradle.

Answer (score 0):

I create a helper class for this. I update the return value in this class before compiling. I use a method instead of a variable to prevent compiler errors for unreachable code.

Then you can check this to decide whether to swap out your link to Google Play.

This allows you to keep just one project and is easy to change. The downside may be the possibility of you forgetting to change it back when compiling for Google Play. That would also be a risk if using compiler options. If you are worried about that, with either of these methods, you could write two separate scripts that change the necessary value and compile for a specific destination.

```
public class CompileConstants {

    public static boolean isAmazonRelease(){
        return true;
    }

}
```